# Regex match with variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using `JavaScript` and would like to match everything in a custom template language like this:

```
Begin10
    Match THIS keyword and ANOTHER
End10
```

So I would like to find `Begin10` using the 10 as variable to find `End10` and match THIS and ANOTHER between them.
I've looked at capture groups. I assume this is the way to go, but I can't figure out how to compose the expression.

`THIS` and `ANOTHER` need to be targeted for syntax highlighting by my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex with captured group

```js
var str = `Begin10
    Match THIS keyword and ANOTHER1
End10

Begin20
    Match THIS keyword and ANOTHER2
End20`;

console.log(
  str.match(/\bBegin(\d+)[\s\S]*?\bEnd\1\b/g)
);
```

---

To get the string between them, do something like this

```js
var str = `Begin10
    Match THIS keyword and ANOTHER1
End10

Begin20
    Match THIS keyword and ANOTHER2
End20`;

var res = [],
  regex = /\bBegin(\d+)\s+([\s\S]*?)\s+\bEnd\1\b/g,
  match;

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
  res.push(match[2]);
}

console.log(res);
```

---

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/sC1cK9/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

**UPDATE :**

If there is only `THIS` or `ANOTHER` between them then use

```js
var str = `Begin10
    THIS
End10

Begin20
    ANOTHER
End20`;

var res = [],
  regex = /\bBegin(\d+)\s+(THIS|ANOTHER)\s+\bEnd\1\b/g,
  match;

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
  res.push(match[2]);
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I am trying to replace [\s\S] in the expression so that I can target `THIS` and `ANOTHER` instead. I don't wish to match the whole string

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: I'd assume a small change like this would work, `/\bBegin(\d+)\s+(THIS|ANOTHER)\s+\bEnd\1\b/g`

Comment: @Ade : only these two strings between them??

Comment: Yes, I first want to find `Begin(\d+)` and match it with (`End\1`) but then I need to search between these strings and find `THIS` and `ANOTHER` only.

Comment: @Ade :  then this will work `/\bBegin(\d+)\s+(THIS|ANOTHER)\s+\bEnd\1\b/g`

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
\bBegin(\d+)\b([\S\s]*)\bEnd\1\b
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD4kQ9/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
\nBegin(\d+)\s*\nMatch \b(\w+)\b keyword and \b(\w+)\b\s*\nEnd\1\n
```

### Explanation:

1. `\n` will match a newline, and I am sure you don't want to get anything besides newline.
2. `\1` that's a variable for the first group to make sure it has the same value.
3. `\s*` just to ignore some unnecessary whitespaces.

Comment: Actually, if you write a good regex, it does not have to be non-greedy.

Comment: But it's a must in this question. I don't think there is other alternative in this case.

Comment: If you do not know a better alternative, it does not mean there is none. Study *unroll the loop* technique to write better regexps.

Comment: I know. Sure! Thank you for letting me know. It's nice to get advanced knowledge in StackOverflow

Comment: I wish to target `THIS` and `ANOTHER` so I can highlight them as keywords. The answers here have already taken me halfway through